# How to detach a DVI port from a circuit board?

Tags: dvi

Motherboard in my monitor seems to be attached to the metal case with the help of a DVI port in addition to a screw. After removing the screw it is still impossible to take the board out of the case. I need to inspect it and replace damaged capacitors if required. Can anyone explain how to disconnect the board from the port?

Comment: Not without seeing it, or knowing what it is. Also, what makes you think it's going to be something as simple as capacitors, or even that you will be able to identify which capacitors, or that they're even mounted as discreet components, solderable?

Comment: @Tetsujin, concerning your question: well, I'm listening what are your suggestions.

Comment: Show us your work. Right now all we're doing is guessing.

Comment: But this was not a question on how to repair damaged circuit boards. You would like to find out what happened to them?

Comment: so… tell us what the board is, or provide a photo. I keep asking, you keep ignoring. My comment on the chance of repair was actually based on your demonstrable skill in taking it apart in the first place.

Comment: At a minimum it would be good to see a photo of the area you think is holding the connector so that we could say for sure.

Comment: @Tetsujin, well, take a look, if it's not too much trouble to you. This is power supply board, motherboard which I disconnected thanks to Mokubai seems to be OK. https://ibb.co/kDxCRr7 https://ibb.co/NjQFgdG

Comment: idk what I'm supposed to be looking for, other than the charred bit top right, which doesn't look promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would unscrew the standoffs connecting the port to the metalwork.

These things should simply unscrew from the connector:

[image]

Comment: Possibly a good bit of mind-reading there;) I'd assumed they already did that….

Comment: @Tetsujin I would assume as much, but there's nothing else I could think of around a DVI connector that would be holding it into the metalwork. Everything else on the actual connector holds it to the PCB... https://uk.farnell.com/molex/74320-1007/dvi-conn-rcpt-29pos/dp/1509323

Comment: For sure - might be me assuming too much, but I'd have thought … "It won't come off. I wonder if taking those two big, obvious nuts out might help?" ;))